# write to file - which way is cleaner?

Tags: java

I am using `java.io.PrintWriter` to write some text to a text file.
I was wondering if it was better to build in a variable all what I need to write and give only once

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputfile);
out.printf("%s", myvariablewithalltext);
```

or if I can call `n` times `PrintWriter` to write block of text in a `for` loop.

It works in either way and there is no much more code, I was just wondering which is better.

Comment: Depends how you built `myvariablewithalltext`

Answer (score 2):

In most cases it's better to write in stream. The main reason is that your variable might take too much memory, but stream will automatically flush it's content. Writing text into the variable is essentially manual buffering. And better way to do it is to use appropriate buffering stream/writer. In you case you can just use `java.io.BufferedWriter`. Like so

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("file.txt"));
```

or, if you prefer PrintWriter interface, you can do this

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt")));
```

Comment: great, thanks.. I didn't know about BufferedWriter.. I will go reading about it but from what I've seen it's advisable to use it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are open for other suggestions (not just the two you mentioned in question).

If all you want is a clean way of writing text to a file, which of course has multiple solutions, here are few ways:

1. Using [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

   example:

   ```
   String contentToWrite = "This is some random Text";
   PrintWriter writerToFile = new PrintWriter("TheOutputFile.txt");
   writerToFile.print(contentToWrite);
   writerToFile.close();
   ```
2. Using [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

   example:

   `String contentToWrite = "This is some random Text";
   FileOutputSream fileOPS = new FileOutputStream("TheOutputFile.txt");
   fileOPS.write(contentToWrite.getBytes());
   fileOPS.close();`
3. Using [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)
4. Using [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) along with [`BufferWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)
5. Using [`FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) by *apache.commons.io*
6. Using [`Files`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) by *guava*

Some approaches here just take the content (no parsing or conversion required i.e in string format) and write that to a file. [ no parsing/conversion -> less code -> cleaner code ]. ;)

Some do not require you to make nesting of objects. [ less objects -> less code -> cleaner code ]. ;)

Of course usage depends on your implementation. but I hope this will help you in making decision what would best suit your requirement.

**Note:** every class name I mentioned is a link to its reference document.

Comment: thanks I will read a bit more... at the moment I just used PrintWriter as it's mentioned in the text book I am using

Answer (score 0):

It is the latter. There is no good reason whatsoever to put the entire content into a variable, just to write it in a file. 
If you have some additional use for that variable beyond writing to file, that might change things a little bit, but even then, there is, probably, a better way.

Comment: thank you.. I would have built the variable only for this scope, so I understand now why it's not advisable. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on your content lenght.

If you have just some litle text, it's better to keep all in memory and write in one shot.

But if your content is very large or if some part take long time to computed, probably you should write piece by piece to avoid have huge data kept in memory.

Comment: Why no mention of `StringBuilder`. Creating large strings by concatenating a bunch of `String`s is a very bad approach. Using `StringBuilder` is preferred.

Comment: Why "is it better to keep all in memory and write in one shot"? What benefits do you have in mind?

Comment: @Dima If there is just few line, it is more expensive to open-close a file descriptor to write on disk this data in several times, it is better to just write all the data in one time. But with huge data or if long to compute, we can write on disk part by part when available, essentially to save memory

Comment: @Dima I'm talking about this part of the question "or if I can call n times PrintWriter to write block of text", i understand that the owner is asking for either writing in one use, either using a PrintWriter several time to complete his operation. But maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: @Prim you can write multiple times to file, without closing and reopening it every time.